# update join and where using Postgres

Tags: postgresql

i have two tables : productprice and product
and i have a field name id on that tables, i would like update field name enddate on productprice base on code on product i try several syntax:

```
update productprice
set enddate = ’2016-12-31 00:00:00’
from product inner join
     productprice
     on product.id = productprice.id
where product.code = ‘9301940252’
```

but the result is "table name “productprice” specified more than once"

What I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for MySQL:

```
update productprice pp join
       product p
       on p.id = pp.id
    set pp.enddate = '2016-12-31' 
    where p.code = '9301940252';
```

Given your error and the fact that the question originally had Postgres and MySQL as a tag, perhaps you want Postgres syntax:

```
update productprice pp
    set enddate = '2016-12-31' 
    from product p
    where p.id = pp.id and p.code = '9301940252';
```

Comment: just to ask. is it okay without AS ? on productprice pp and product p? :)

Comment: @jace . . . Yes.  I use `as` for column aliases, but never for table aliases.

Comment: oh :) cause I also do on table names :) not knowing it is possible not to . thanks

Comment: still doesn't work with error
ERROR: syntax error at or near "join"
line 1 = update productprice pp join product p

Comment: it depends on your database structure (ERD) :) can you post a screenshots of your tables?

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: yep i am using mysql and postgresql

Comment: @DADANGRAMADHAN . . . Those are very different databases.  You would normally be using one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh i am using postgresql, sorry my mistakes